# wrong behaviour (wrong display position) of a <select> in a jquery-ui dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, html-select

A `<select>` input in the declaration of a jquery-ui dialog is not displaying in the right place. It is always at the top of the dialog !

Here is the code :

```
<div id="newarticle-form" title="Cr&eacute;ation nouvel article">
    <form action="http://localhost/ravioles/administration/articleAjout" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="newarticleform">  <fieldset>
        <label for="code" class="label-class">Code article</label>
        <input type="text" name="code" id="code" size="6" maxlength="6" class="text input-class" />
        <label for="validite" class="label-class">Date de validit&eacute;</label>
        <input type="text" name="validite" id="validite" size="10" maxlength="10" class="text input-class" />
        <label for="libelle" class="label-class">Libell&eacute;</label>
        <input type="text" name="libelle" id="libelle" size="50" maxlength="100" class="text input-class" />
        <label for="poids" class="label-class">Poids (g)</label>
        <input type="text" name="poids" id="poids" value="" size="5" maxlength="5" class="text input-class" />
        <label for="pu" class="label-class">Prix unitaire</label>
        <input type="text" name="pu" id="pu" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" class="text input-class" />
        <label for="categorie" class="label-class">Cat&eacute;gorie</label>
        <select id="categorie" >
            <option value="00001">RAVIOLES</option>
            <option value="00002">PATES FRAICHES DU ROYAN</option>
            <option value="00003">PATES FARCIES DU ROYAN</option>
            <option value="00004">QUENELLES</option>
            <option value="00005">TRAITEUR</option>
            <option value="00006">SAVEURS EXPRESS</option>
            <option value="00007">CONSERVES ET SAUCES</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
        <p class="validateTips"></p>
</div>
```

The dialog in javascript :

```
$( "#newarticle-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 700,
    modal: true,
    resizable:false,
    buttons: {
        "Ajouter article": function() {
            bla bla bla ...
        },

        "Fermer": function() {
            $(this).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },

    close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
    },
});
```

It's a quiet difficult to give the right position to the elements of a jquery-ui dialog box.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: See if you can get a demo going and put the updated link in your question. Here's a start: http://jsfiddle.net/YU9BT/

Comment: Thanks Isherwood ! In the jsfiddle you made, the dropdown is at the right place. Not in my application... There is to significant css code to explain why. I'll try with a table to force the display position of the element. However, I'm still searching why this strange behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the good solution but I succeed with a table in the dialog :

```
<div id="newarticle-form" title="Cr&eacute;ation nouvel article">
    <form action="http://localhost/ravioles/administration/articleAjout" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="newarticleform">  <fieldset>
        <table><tr><td>
            <label for="code" class="label-class">Code article</label>
            <input type="text" name="code" id="code" size="6" maxlength="6" class="text input-class" />
        </td></tr><tr><td>
            <label for="validite" class="label-class">Date de validit&eacute;</label>
            <input type="text" name="validite" id="validite" size="10" maxlength="10" class="text input-class" />
        </td></tr><tr><td>
            <label for="libelle" class="label-class">Libell&eacute;</label>
            <input type="text" name="libelle" id="libelle" size="50" maxlength="100" class="text input-class" />
        </td></tr><tr><td>
            <label for="poids" class="label-class">Poids (g)</label>
            <input type="text" name="poids" id="poids" value="" size="5" maxlength="5" class="text input-class" />
        </td></tr><tr><td>
            <label for="pu" class="label-class">Prix unitaire</label>
            <input type="text" name="pu" id="pu" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" class="text input-class" />
        </td></tr><tr><td>
            <label for="categorie" class="label-class">Cat&eacute;gorie</label>
            <select id="categorie" >
            <option value="00001">RAVIOLES</option>
            <option value="00002">PATES FRAICHES DU ROYAN</option>
            <option value="00003">PATES FARCIES DU ROYAN</option>
            <option value="00004">QUENELLES</option>
            <option value="00005">TRAITEUR</option>
            <option value="00006">SAVEURS EXPRESS</option>
            <option value="00007">CONSERVES ET SAUCES</option>
        </select><br>
        </td></tr></table>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
        <p class="validateTips"></p>
</div>
```

Thank you ! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. Oddly the dialog would move up to the top when adding either `<hr />` or `<select>` elements. Wrapping the elements in a table fixed the issue.

```
<select>...</select>
<hr />
<more content>
```

became

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><select>...</select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><more content></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

good luck to anyone else that finds this!
Bo